# How can i use my Pixma 6150 as scanner?

Tags: canon, scanner, pixma

I bought a Canon PIXMA MG6150 and i am new at ubuntu. With the drivers from Canon i got it running a as a printer, but i have problems using it as scanner. With the Canon drivers it runs under GIMP with Scangear MP. But i want to use XSANE or gscan2pdf and in these programs it doesn't work. They tell me that no devices are available. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Canon has chosen not to provide official support for Ubuntu, and this limits what you can do. To make a PDF of a scanned document first scan it in GIMP, save the .jpg image, then drag the .jpg image into a new document in Libre Office. Export the document as a PDF. Done.

Comment: @TomBrossman Add as answer Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed the drivers from Canon, the ScanGear application is there too.

Run `scangearmp`. That command can be added into a `.desktop` file, like [so](https://askubuntu.com/a/725412/47206).

Or run from Gimp: File-Create-SangearMP.

ScanGear can save as pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Canon has chosen not to provide official support for Ubuntu, and this limits what you can do. You can't use it with gscan2pdf, for example.

To make a PDF of a scanned document:

1. Scan it in GIMP
2. Save the .jpg image
3. Drag the .jpg image into a new document in Libre Office
4. Export the document as a PDF

Experiment with both the image scan quality, as well as the PDF export quality, to get a reasonably small PDF. I usually scan at 300dpi, then adjust the PDF export quality to get the best results.

Comment: This is so inefficient. And how do you scan 40 pages contract?

Comment: @Kave Agreed. Scan a 40 page contract by getting rid of the Canon and replacing it with a HP machine, then scan like normal with gscan2pdf. Or, try scanning the docs standalone and save to a USB thumb drive plugged in to the scanner. There is no other way until Canon provides a utility or provides source code.

Comment: I didn't think about the USB stick. Thats a great solution. Thank you :) Its also much faster since its done by hardware. A shame Canon is so Linux unfriendly. Which HP All-in-One Printer or else would you recommend that supports Ubuntu?

Comment: @Kave I was being a bit sarcastic,  Canon provides some Linux support which I appreciate.  HP's Linux support has historically been far better. Just search here or look on Amazon and search the user reviews for 'Ubuntu' to find one.