# Is the scanner Canon Pixma MG2450 working in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 15.04, scanner, pixma

The [Canon Pixma MG2450](http://www.canon.fr/printers/inkjet/pixma/pixma_mg2450/) printer has an integrated scanner that should work with a tool like Simple Scan (or `xsane` or Skanlite).

[image]

There are two sets of drivers ([provided by Canon](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2450.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20%2864-bit%29) as deb files): two drivers for the printer (`cnijfilter-common`and `cnijfilter-mg2400series`) and two for the scanner (`scangearmp-common` and `scangearmp-mg2400series`). All drivers can be installed just fine, the printer works, but the scanner is not detected.

As seen [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON), the Canon Pixma 2400 series is supported.

How can I use this 2 in 1 scanner / printer?

---

I have tried to use Xubuntu, Kubuntu and Lubuntu, eOS and Mint, and got the same negative results.

Note that **the scanner works in Windows**.

How can I get it working?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: Have you checked the system logs for anything suspicious?

Comment: Have you done `dpkg -L scangearmp-common;dpkg -L scangearmp-mg2400series` and read the interesting files?

Comment: @waltinator - reading such files is beyond my skill. I just want to know if I could make it work or not, I'm a user that reads  a lot, but not used "reading" system files

Comment: **Please comment before down-voting, in order to help me correct what is amiss**

Comment: @cat - 14.04 kubuntu; It is beyond my skill inding if anything is suspicious or not, beyond what I reported.  I just want to know if this scanner is supported or not to keep trying or give up

Comment: @cipricus [that's not why I downvoted.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/is-this-cross-post-against-site-rules)

Comment: @cat - You just prove U&L is against cross-posting. [Not askubuntu.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6032/47206). Posting on U&L was useless  for me so I posted here. Down vote me there not here. On second thoughts don't do it, as I'll delete that question there  after the bounty expires :)

Comment: @cipricus every site on SE is against cross-posting. That is mentioned in various places on [the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101) and that includes AU. U&L is more strict than most but pretty much every site is against it. That said, your question on U&L mentions other distros and has more detail and, as I explained in [my answer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3870/22222) on the relevant meta post, doesn't really qualify as cross-posting.

Comment: @terdon - great, I'll keep them both for the moment then., and maybe delete one of them when I get a good answer on the other. In fact I'll even test with something like Manjaro and post results in the U&L question.

Comment: @cat - please look at tendon's comment saying it's not a crossposting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drivers already mentioned in the question are just fine, only they cannot be used with the Simple San or Xsane tools, but they install a tool  called **ScanGear** that can be launched with the command `scangearmp`.

[image]

[image]

Outputs: **png, pdf, pnm**.

To add a `.desktop` launcher for that:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/scan.desktop
```

and paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Graphics;Scanning;
Exec=scangearmp
Icon=scanner
Name=Scan
Type=Application
```

The same can be used within Gimp: **File/Create/ScanGear MP**, but S**canGear does not need Gimp in order to work**.

Sources are linked in my other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257523/32012).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding the [SANE daily build ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git) to your system and updating.  This gained functionality of a Canon multifunction printer/scanner on our system in `xsane`.  Everything works except the document feeder, which I have posted a separate question about.  If Canon provides `scangearmp2` for your printer, does that work?  It works on our system, including document feeder, but has a limited feature set compared to `xsane`.

Comment: When you run `xsane` what error message / popup do you get?  Also, are you using the scanner over a LAN or via USB?

Comment: Scangear2 for our MB2320 can be found here https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/small-office-home-office-printers/mb2320

Comment: After solving it I understand what you mean. **The scanner driver from Cannon comes with a separate GUI application called *ScanGear***. One doesn't need Xsane or Simple Scan, nor Gimp as some say to use that, although it can be run from Gimp. It can be run simply as `scangearmp` in my case. - Adding Sane daily ppa is a very bad idea in my case it gave me dependency problems, I had to remove it to get back my old version and be able to use the driver that I already had but didn't knew how to use.